# force screen on, during Fragment replacement

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service, android-windowmanager, android-wake-lock

i have a master activity and some fragments inside that . on a particular event i replace a fragment and during that i need to force screen on to notify user. i've used wakelock for that

```
PowerManager.WakeLock screenOn = ((PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "tag");
        screenOn.acquire();
```

but i know that its not recommended and on some devices cause screen blinking on lock screens.another approach might be adding flags on window manager when i'm starting the master activity :

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

but this works just on situations when that event raised on a service and activity just created that moment and not turning screen on when activity already exist and user just pressing power button and gone to lock screen.i'm thinking of replacing that fragment with an activity but at current app logic its not desirable. can anybody recommend me a better way for that?